# JavaFX in Eclipse Helios: IllegalArgumentException (Css2Bin.java:44)

Tags: javafx-2

I got this error while trying to start and make javafx 2.0 in eclipse helios

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected file name as argument
at com.sun.javafx.css.parser.Css2Bin.main(Css2Bin.java:44)
```

Recently I'm following step-by-step to Getting Started with JavaFX 2.0 in Eclipse IDE
from this - [website](http://zoranpavlovic.blogspot.com/2012/05/getting-started-with-javafx-in-eclipse.html) 
I don't know how to fix it, can somebody help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add the jfxrt.jar to Build Path
- Go to properties jfxrt.jar in Referenced Libraries
- GO to Run/Debug Settings>Css2Bin
- Mark the check box:

  - Include system libraries when searching for a main class
  - Include inherited mains when searching for a main class

Now be happy!

Comment: I also have the problem as described by user1533670 and this does not change anything with Java 1.7u25/FX 2.2 in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

**Well, these answers seem to say what you need to do, but they're not very straight-forward.**

1. You right click the project, and click Properties.
2. Select Run/Debug Settings.
3. Click Css2Bin.
4. Delete it.

*Trust me I tried it and it works.*

Answer (score 1):

This problem comes from Css2Bin being set as the application to run. This means that eclipse tries to run Css2Bin as your main application and Css2Bin crashes when it doesn't receive any command line arguments.

Easiest way to solve this is to remove Css2Bin from you run/debug settings (project settings) and add one where you select your own application in the menus.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't depend on running in helios I'd suggest you'd give e(fx)clipse a try. You can find it at http://www.efxclipse.org/

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem (in e(fx)clipse).  I tried the solution mentioned above and still had the same problem.  I added a new run configuration and pointed it directly to the class thar had Main and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy you need to have a main Class that extends Application Class for Launch the Args like that :

```
public class Test extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Launch the Application 
        launch(args);   

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        //JavaFx load the GUI from FXML file ... super 
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("yourGUI.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("App Name");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have added jfxrt.jar into reference libraries...

Now

Right Click your Project -> Properities -> Run/Debug Settings -> Click the Css2Bin ->

Main Class:

Click the Search button

**to change com.sun.javafx.css.parser.Css2Bin into your project main class**

and

Mark the checkbox

- Include system libraries when searching for a main class
- Include inherited mains when searching for a main class

Answer (score -1):

we can run as the Appllcation to solve the problem

Comment: You should add more to your answer , although I don't believe running the application will solve any problem.