# JavaFX java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (Css2Bin.java:44)

Tags: javafx

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

public class Main 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String bip = "bip.mp3";
        Media hit = new Media(bip);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
        mediaPlayer.play();
    }

}
```

This spits out:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected file name as argument
    at com.sun.javafx.css.parser.Css2Bin.main(Css2Bin.java:44)

First time trying to use this new fangled javaFx.. So It's the first time I have seen this Css2Bin stuff.As a result I have no idea what it means. Or what it wants from me.

All I really wanted to do is play a piece of mp3 but that seems to be to hard for the standard API....

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14207511/2587435) helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run a javafx api on java demon thread. Inorder to use javafx specific utilities, they must run on javafx thread. Please try the following, as whatever you write inside `start()` is running on `Javafx Thread` :

```
public class Welcome extends Application {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        launch(args);  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {  
        primaryStage.setTitle("Media");
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 540, 209,Color.BLUEVIOLET);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        String bip = "bip.mp3";
        Media hit = new Media(bip);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
        //set player property to autoplay
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);

        // Create the view and add it to the Scene.
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(mediaView);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```