# Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.javafx.css.parser.Css2Bin

Tags: javafx

I want to install JavaFX on Eclipse.

I have installed JDK 13 e(fx)clipse 3.6 and JavaFX 14.

When I run a Project I get the error message:

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.javafx.css.parser.Css2Bin
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.css.parser.Css2Bin

What is wrong?

Comment: You don't need e(fx)clipse to write JavaFX projects. In any case, does this help? [JavaFX in Eclipse Helios: IllegalArgumentException (Css2Bin.java:44)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584356/javafx-in-eclipse-helios-illegalargumentexception-css2bin-java44)

Comment: i will use the javaFX webview component

Comment: how can i use javafx wihout e(fx)clpse

Comment: I use Eclipse IDE for Java Developers. I don't use Scene Builder or FXML files. I simply add the JavaFX JAR files to the build path of my project in Eclipse. If that is suitable for you, I can add an answer to your question detailing all the steps required.